# Why can't I access a mongodb query result outside of a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Why can't I access my result?

```
var myList = [];
db.collection('clientes').find({}, {projection: {_id:0, pedido: 1}}).toArray((err, result) => {
   if (err) return console.log(err);
   myList.push(result);
})
console.log(myList);`
```

My console log is giving me 'undefined', why?

Comment: Doubtful.  Check that assumption again... there's something else wrong in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: It's an **asynchronous** function. The callback is only called when the query is complete.

Comment: `console.log` is executed before you get the results